# How Grab CSV from a Website using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Hello I'm having issues grabbing an excel sheet from vba

my code is as follow:

```
Sub transfercsv()

sCSVLink = "http://ets.aeso.ca/Market/Reports/Manual/Operations/prodweb_reports/wind_power_forecast/WPF_ShortTerm.csv"
sfile = "options_code_list.csv"
ssheet = "CSV Transfer"


Dim myURL As String
myURL = "http://ets.aeso.ca/Market/Reports/Manual/Operations/prodweb_reports/wind_power_forecast/WPF_ShortTerm.csv"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile ("C:\file.csv")
    oStream.Close

End If
```

Right now when the code runs, it chops off the data that I am trying to save down. Any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean 'chops off'? Are you viewing it in notepad? Can you compare file sizes between when VBA does and when you manually do it? Does it have to be done in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an issue with the data being cutoff, it seems like anyone can run this report.

I cleaned up the approach to as there seemed to be some variables not needed and some other issues. Revised code below.

**Code**

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub SOExample()
    Const OutputFilePath As String = "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\file.csv"
    Const myURL As String = "http://ets.aeso.ca/Market/Reports/Manual/Operations/prodweb_reports/wind_power_forecast/WPF_ShortTerm.csv"
    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Dim response() As Byte

    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", myURL, False
        .Send
        response = .ResponseBody
    End With

    If UBound(response) > 0 Then

        'Delete the file before saving?
        With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            If .FileExists(OutputFilePath) Then Kill OutputFilePath
        End With

        With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            .Open
            .Type = adTypeBinary
            .Write response
            .SaveToFile (OutputFilePath)
            .Close
        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim wb
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("http://ets.aeso.ca/Market/Reports/Manual/Operations/" & _
                        "prodweb_reports/wind_power_forecast/WPF_ShortTerm.csv")

Debug.Print wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count '>> 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple ideas for you to try.

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Dim myURL As String
myURL = "http://www.asx.com.au/data/options_code_list.csv"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Coding\Microsoft Excel\Bank of China\downloadCSV.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub


Sub transfercsv()
sCSVLink = "http://www.asx.com.au/data/options_code_list.csv"
sfile = "options_code_list.csv"
ssheet = "CSV Transfer"

Set wnd = ActiveWindow
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets(ssheet).Cells.ClearContents
Workbooks.Open Filename:=sCSVLink
Windows(sfile).Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
wnd.Activate
Sheets("CSV Transfer").Paste
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Windows(sfile).Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```